# get 2 different url using xmlhttp.open

Tags: javascript, gm-xmlhttprequest

Need help on this following code. the problem is it only trigger the last xmlhttp.open not both. code as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(obj){ 
  var xmlhttp; 
  var flag; 
  var mycode;
  mycode = obj;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    }
  }
   flag = document.getElementById(mycode);
   if (flag.value == "Uncall") {
     flag.value = "Call Patient";
     document.getElementById('myDiv'+mycode).innerHtml="<b><font color='#00FF00'>Called</font></b>";        
   }else{ 
     flag.value = "Uncall";
     document.getElementById('myDiv'+mycode).innerHtml="<b><font color='#00FF00'>Calling..</font></b>";
     **xmlhttp.open("GET","http://1.1.1.1/callnumber.cgi?"+mycode,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
     xmlhttp.open("GET","http://2.2.2.2/displaynumber.php?"+mycode,true);
     xmlhttp.send();**
   }
}
</script>
```

appreciate some input

Comment: If you read [the documentation for the `open` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method) you'll se that one of the things it does is cancel a previous send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(obj){
  var xmlhttp; 
  var flag;
  var mycode;
  mycode = obj;
  flag = document.getElementById(mycode);
  if (flag.value != "Uncall"){
      loadXMLDocCall(obj,"http://1.1.1.1/callnumber.cgi?");
      loadXMLDocCall(obj,"http://2.2.2.2/displaynumber.php?");
      flag.value = "Uncall";
      document.getElementById('myDiv'+mycode).innerHtml="<b><font color='#00FF00'>Calling..</font></b>";
      } else { 
       flag.value = "Call Patient";
       document.getElementById('myDiv'+mycode).innerHtml="<b><font color='#00FF00'>Called</font></b>";
      }
}
function loadXMLDocCall(obj,url){ 
  var xmlhttp; 
  var mycode;
  mycode = obj;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    }
  }
   xmlhttp.open("GET",url+mycode,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
</script>
```

Comment: refering to "xmlhttp.open("GET",url+mycode,true);" what is the value of url?

Comment: i've edited my answer so you dont have to change any code in html

Comment: I've edited again. It now avoids conflits because of your div flag.

Comment: great the code works! as advise. thanks Ciro for the great help.

Comment: Code like this that gets marked as the right way to do things is why people think JavaScript is an awful language. Glad it works for you though.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reuse the same request object.

Best advice is don't write any of this yourself. Find a library and use their implementation. JQuery isn't bad. There are plenty of other options too.

Comment: fyi, the code works and im editing the existing apps. mission is to pass the same variable to different url. really appreciate help or suggestion. thanks